# Can I do PiFM, just on 13.56mhz?

Tags: gpio, pifm

I want to broadcast on 13.56mhz from the GPIO pins, just like with PiFM (except PiFM is like 85-105mhz). Is there a simple way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

PiFM support modulation frequency selection. Try starting it with `--freq 13.56`. You will get a warning that your frequency is outside of FM range, but PiFM will make an attempt to configure the frequency nevertheless.